# Running an Ionic project cloned from git

Tags: ionic-framework

I've inherited an Ionic project which I've cloned from git but none of the plug ins are working. Is there a step I have to do after cloning to initialise the plug ins?

Comment: have you followed the setup guide [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) to ensure you've met all the dependencies? Otherwise you may need to provide more info to get help - what you have tried, what the plugins are etc.

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install` and `bower install` from the command line. Assuming you've got bower and node/npm installed.

Comment: It didn't work.  It's like the no cordova plug ins aren't working.  I've done an ionic state reset as well.